# Installing or updating symfony/flex via Composer silently fails

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a project using symfony/flex in which I cannot run `composer install` or `composer update`. I also can't create a new composer project with symfony/flex as a dependency as the failure is the same. For example;

```
mkdir foo && cd foo && composer require symfony/flex -vvv
```

Always has the following output;

```
...
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: symfony/flex:v1.2.6
  - Installing symfony/flex (v1.2.6): Reading /Users/me/.composer/cache/files/symfony/flex/17b622276922e6347ea129acd6238ae1c41d96b6.zip from cache
Loading from cache
 Extracting archiveExecuting command (CWD): unzip -qq  '/Users/me/projects/foo/vendor/symfony/flex/2064a553f7cdf064ba8c1b62c7087ec6' -d '/Users/me/projects/foo/vendor/composer/65215880'
Loading plugin Symfony\Flex\Flex
Downloading https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json
```

The download hangs for a few seconds at the point of downloading versions.json before silently failing. `vendor/symfony/flex` exists.

What could be the cause of this failure? My colleague can run the same command successfully so I'm assuming an issue with my local composer. I have attempted reinstall composer and clearing the cache with no success.

**Edit:** now when running `composer update -vvv` in an existing project I get the following output

```
...
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
```

Where it also hangs, so it looks like composer cannot download certain JSON files? Packages download fine so it doesn't look like a lack of internet.

**Edit 2:** I can also confirm using `composer update --no-plugins` does work within the existing project.

Comment: Try to go to a new directory and do `composer install` and follow steps

Comment: @weegee I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Create an empty folder in foo eg. Test. Then do `cd Test` then do `composer install`

Comment: Oh I see - same issue occurs

Comment: My ISP has screwed up IPv6 and I had to disable it on my machine to reach Composer.

Answer (score 18):

When composer isn't working as expected, you should reset it and update it like this. First

```
$ composer clearcache
```

Then update

```
$ composer self-update
```

Then run a diagnostic

```
$ composer diagnose
```

Then cd to where you have composer.json located and do

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

Then

```
$ composer install
```

Should fix this issue. Another approach includes

```
$ composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

Also, this can arise due to a conflict between `symfony/flex` and `symfony/symfony`. To remove that conflict follow these steps

```
$ composer remove symfony/symfony
```

then edit your `composer.json` file like

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
     },
     "conflict": {
         "symfony/symfony": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: No difference sadly, it still hangs on `Downloading https://flex.symfony.com/versions.json` and silently dies. Using `--no-plugins` is the only thing that allows the install to run.

Comment: Okay, try to go to a new directory (empty one) and then run these commands then do composer install. Check your internet connection too. Check for any vendor folder

Comment: I've tried this process many a time - the end result is the same. Connection is fine - if I clear the composer cache the actual package downloads with no issues, it's just the versions.json file that either refuses to download, or some other silent error occurs.

Comment: Do you have symfony/symfony installed?. Maybe that's the issue

Comment: When testing this in a new directory I'm only installing `symfony/flex`, so that's the only direct dependency. I have just tried the exact same command from a server of mine and it installed no problem. I'm curious if it's related to being on a coffee shop WiFi network, but I don't see why.

Comment: It can be due to a conflict between `symfony/symfony` and `symfony/flex` check if you have both installed.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it now @ChrisBrown

Comment: Again - I only have symfony/flex installed when testing in a new folder (and also in the existing project which is failing), symfony/symfony is not installed in either location.

Comment: Did you try this? `composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts`

Comment: Yes I edited the original question - `--no-plugins` does prevent the issue because it doesn't run `flex`, but that effectively confirms the issue is at least related to flex, but seems specific to my dev environment.

Answer (score 7):

Old Flex infrastructure is being shut down, you need to update Flex to AT LEAST 1.17.1: symfony.com/blog/upgrade-flex-on-your-symfony-projects

To do that, you need to run:

```
composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this, solved my issue

```
> composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

then keep this config in my composer.json

```
  {
    "require": {
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
     },
     "conflict": {
         "symfony/symfony": "*"
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since my experience is with the same issue and thus not deserving of a standalone Q&A, I'll just post it as an answer to this, as the core problem is exactly the same, Symfony flex servers being shut down.

In my dockered project, dependencies were not being installed during build and after some investigation I found out, that `composer install` would always fail due to being unable to reach the Symfony flex server. It looked like a DNS problem at first, but it ended up being a problem with Symfony flex servers being shut down and an old version (1.3) of "symfony/flex" in composer.json.

I did pretty much everything in the most upvoted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56603653/6453155), but

```
$ composer update symfony/flex --no-plugins --no-scripts
```

returned an error due to a dependency of the symfony/flex package hitting the API limit. However as suggested I created a Personal access token and everything went smoothly from there.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem.

I added cloudflare dns 1.1.1.1 to my dns.

This solved it for me

Comment: This is not the correct solution, you're just riding on stale DNS cache, it will expire soon.

Old flex infrastructure is being shut down, you need to update Flex: https://symfony.com/blog/upgrade-flex-on-your-symfony-projects